# Sequencing a part number using User Form

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely new in VBA or programming. Right now I am developing a macro for a manufacturing site that inputs process data using Excel's User Forms. One of the things I want this macro to do is to automatically create run numbers for each process. The run number syntax we use is as follows:

V1.yy.mm.dd-1

V1.yy.mm.dd-2

V1.yy.mm.dd-3

Ex V1.20.04.29-1

The way I am trying to set up the run number creation is that when I select an item from a ComboBox the part number gets created into a TextBox to later be submitted into the corresponding database. I am not sure how to create a sequence after the Prefix = V1.yy.mm.dd-, I tried to use a CountIf application that would count the number of Prefixes with the same date in the spreadsheet for sequencing, but it seems the function does not work for partial matches. I tried to use the following but I can't get it to work. I am sure there are simpler ways to do this, can you give me a few suggestions? Thanks

This is the code I wrote so far:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

If Me.ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then

Dim Prefix As String
Dim mm, dd, yy As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2- V1 Loading (2)")
Dim s As Long

s = 1 + sh.Application.Count(Application.Match(Prefix, Range("B:B"), 0))

mm = Format(Date, "mm")
dd = Format(Date, "dd")
yy = Format(Date, "yy")

Prefix = "V1." & yy & "." & mm & "." & dd & "-"
v1 = "V1." & yy & "." & mm & "." & dd & "-" & "" & s

Me.TextBox6.Value = v1


End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

If Me.ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2- V1 Loading (2)")

oDate = Format(Date, "yy.mm.dd")
oConst = "V1." & oDate & "-"

Range("B1:B10000").Copy Destination:=Range("zz1") 'copy all the item to helper column
Range("zz:zz").Replace What:=oConst, Replacement:="" 'get only the number from all the items with the current date
nextNum = Application.Max(Range("zz:zz")) + 1 'get the next number

MsgBox oConst & CStr(nextNum) 'this line only for checking

Range("zz:zz").ClearContents 'clear the helper column

Me.TextBox6.Value = oConst & CStr(nextNum)


End If
```

But this assuming that the item number in columns B is only  at the same day.
If for example there is a forgotten data from any day before the current day, and this want to be inputted with that day and the next number, it need an input box or maybe a cell in sheet where the value is that day, then it will give the last number of that day.

Suppose the data in column B is something like below:
[image]

If the code is run today, it will show V1.20.04.30-4 as the next number. With the same data like above, if the code is run tomorrow, it will give V1.20.05.01-1.

To get the next number from yesterday (29 Apr 2020), the code need more line - which is to know on what day the code must get the next number.

Or this kind of line maybe is shorter:

```
oConst = "V1." & Format(Date, "yy.mm.dd") & "-"
nextNum = oConst & Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), "*" & oConst & "*") + 1
MsgBox nextNum
```

Comment: This works as a charm, thank you for explaining each line of code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could go about this but I'd say the easiest would be to put the incrementing run number in a separate cell somewhere on your worksheet (or another one if you want) to reference each time.

For example:

When the data is entered onto your 'database' sheet, write the run value to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2- V1 Loading (2)").Range("AZ1")`.

Then in your code check that value like so:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

If Me.ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then

Dim Prefix As String
Dim mm, dd, yy As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2- V1 Loading (2)")
Dim s As Long

s = 1 + sh.Range("AZ1").Value

mm = Format(Date, "mm")
dd = Format(Date, "dd")
yy = Format(Date, "yy")

Prefix = "V1." & yy & "." & mm & "." & dd & "-"
v1 = "V1." & yy & "." & mm & "." & dd & "-" & s

Me.TextBox6.Value = v1
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that the reference numbers are written to column B of the *2- V1 Loading (2)* tab then the next number must always be the one found at the bottom of the column + 1. If there is no number for that date than the new sequential number should be 1. The code below implements that method

```
Function NextRef() As String
    ' 016

    Dim Fun As String
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Fnd As Range
    Dim Sp() As String

    Fun = Format(Date, """V1.""yy.mm.dd")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2- V1 Loading (2)")
        ' start in row 2 (row 1 holding column captions)
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    End With

    If Rng.Row > 1 Then                 ' skip, if the column is empty
        ' finds the first occurrence of Ref from the bottom
        Set Fnd = Rng.Find(What:=Fun, _
                           After:=Rng.Cells(1), _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           LookAt:=xlPart, _
                           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
            Sp = Split(Fnd.Value, "-")
            If UBound(Sp) Then Counter = Val(Sp(1))
        End If
    End If

    NextRef = Fun & -(Counter + 1)
End Function
```

You  can use the function simply like `ComboBox1.Value = NextRef`. However when and how to call that line of code is a bit unclear in your design as published. Especially, it's not clear why you would want it in a ComboBox at all, given that the box might also contain other information. Your idea to use the Change event may not work as intended because that event occurs with every letter the user types. I have tested this:-

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_GotFocus()
    ' 016

    With ComboBox1
        If .Value = "" Then .Value = NextRef
    End With
End Sub
```

The next reference number is inserted as soon as you click on the ComboBox. It works but it doesn't make sense. I think now that you have the function that does the work you will find a way to deploy it. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the ComboBox I use it to select other information prior to the creation of the part number then the created part number goes into TextBox6. Thank you for reaching out and showing me a way to create a sequence.